# Reading values of an Javascript object with various keys

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am looking for a solution for the following problem. I am working with an object that looks:

```
0: {userId: 139, moveId: 169, moveName: "FirstRoadMove", building: {…}}
1: {userId: 139, moveId: 171, moveName: "FirstRoadMove", building: {…}}
2: {userId: 139, moveId: 173, moveName: "FirstRoadMove", building: {…}}
3: {userId: 139, moveId: 175, moveName: "FirstRoadMove", building: {…}}
4: {userId: 139, moveId: 177, moveName: "FirstRoadMove", building: {…}}
5: {userId: 139, moveId: 179, moveName: "FirstRoadMove", building: {…}}
```

And I also have a  component:

```
    <button className={`actionBoxButton ${props.moves[0].moveName !== "FirstSettlementMove"  ? "actionBoxButtonGrey" : ''}`}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to not only check for the button if the first elements of moves has a key with value FirstSettlementMove e.g. but every element of the object. So in semi pseudo something like:

```
    <button className={`actionBoxButton ${props.moves[first to last].moveName !== "FirstSettlementMove"  ? "actionBoxButtonGrey" : ''}`}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you want that on one button or more buttons based on that ? and what do you want to acheive if say on of the ```moveName``` is something other than "FirstSettelmentMove"

Comment: Now it maybe does make more sense, so I want to check if in the moves object, there is an moveName with vale "FirstSettlementMove" and if not do "actionBoxButtonGrey" : ''

Answer (score 2):

You could change your way of thinking. Instead of trying to check all sub object with moveName = firstSettleMentMove, you could check if there is a sub object without this value by doing as follow:

`props.move.filter(x => x.moveName !== 'FirstSettlementMove').length > 0`

If props.move isn't an array, you can still use `Array.from(props.move)` to convert it.

Also, if your object has indexes as you showed us, you can 'remove' it with `Object.values(props.move)`.